# Uniform continuity of $\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is $f(x)=\ln(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(1,+\infty)$? If so, how to show it?

I know how to show that it is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, by taking $x=\frac{1}{\exp(n)}$ and $y = \frac{1}{\exp(n+1)}$.

Also, on which interval does $\ln(x)$ satisfy the Lipschitz condition?

Comment: The logarithm is Lipshitz on any interval where its derivative $x\to\frac1x$ is bounded. And the derivative is bounded if ... ?

Comment: For me $\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded on$ [a,+\infty) $ where $a>0$ by $f(a)$ but the $\ln$ isnt uniform continouity on the interval. And i thought that lipschitz implies uniform continuity.

Comment: x @aiki: Why do you think the logarithm isn't uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty]$ with $a>0$?

Comment: ok sorry, my mistake. So the interval where $\ln(x)$ is uniformly continuous and where satisfy Lipschitz condition is this same? $A=[a,\infty)$ with $a>0$ But lipschitz and uniformly continuous isnt equivalent right? Is any exemple function uniformly continuous but not satisfy lipschitz?

Comment: x @aki: A Lipschitz function is always uniformly continuous, but for example $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,a]$ without being Lipschitz.

Comment: Note, by the way, that there is no "the" interval where the logarithm is Lipschitz -- there are many different intervals where this is the case.

Comment: Using only the elementary inequalities $\frac{x}{x-1}\le \log(x)\le x-1$, we have 

$$\begin{align}
|\log(x)-\log(y)|&=|\log(x/y)|\\\\
&\le \left|\max\left(\frac{x-y}{y},\frac{y-x}{x}\right)\right|\\\\\
&\le |x-y|
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7):

**HINT** Every differentiable function that has bounded derivative on a set $X$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x,y\in(1,+\infty)$  then by mean value theorem there's $z$ such that
$$\log(x)-\log(y)=\frac{1}{z}(x-y)$$
hence we have
\begin{array}\\
|\log(x)-\log(y) |&\leq\sup_{z>1}\frac{1}{z}|x-y|\\&\leq|x-y|
\end{array}
so  the function $\log$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $(1,+\infty)$ since it satisfies the lipschitz condition.

Comment: The interval where f is uniform continuity and satisfy lipschitz condition is the same?

Comment: @aiki93 The function is uniformly convergent on $(0,+\infty)$ but the lipschitz condition is satisfied on every interval $[a,+\infty)$ where $a>0$ so the answer is no.

Comment: @aiki93 yes lipscitz implies uniform continuity but here the function is lipschitz on the interval $[a,+\infty)$ and it's not lipschitz on the interval $(0,+\infty)$. I hope that's clear.

Comment: So why the function isnt uniform comtinuity on $[a,+\infty)$ where satisfy lipschitz but is uniform continuity on interval $[b,+\infty) where b>1

Comment: @aiki93 Ah sorry I correct the mistake the function has uniform continuity on the interval $[a,+\infty)$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8224/discussion-between-aiki93-and-sami-ben-romdhane)

Comment: Is the theorem you used here the regular mean value theorem or is this LaGrange (using the derivative of ln?)

Comment: @user1685224 this  is the mean value theorem so it's also the Taylor-Lagrange theorem at order $1$.

Comment: Well... could you elaborate a little more how you got to the expression with logx-logy , something is missing in my understanding.. Thanks

Comment: @user1685224 The mean value theorem for $f$ is : there's $\xi\in(x,y)$ s.t. $$f(x)-f(y)=f'(\xi)(x-y)$$ and in our case we have $f=\ln$ so $f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to show $x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Then try to establish $\ln(x)-\ln(y)<|x-y|$ for $x,y$ large enough.